# Make VB.Net DatePicker Required

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datepicker

I have a datepicker in a vb.net clickonce application.  I need to make sure that in order to use the application that selecting a valid date is required.  Ideally, I would be able to set the value of the datepicker to null and then programatically create Try Catch logic based on datepicker1.value still being null.  Unfortunately, it will not allow me to assign a null or blank value to the datepicker.  I cannot create my logic based on any real values of the datepicker because who's to say the value picked is not valid.  I've tried setting the value to some outrageous date that no one would pick for the application like 1/1/1970, but then the datepicker opens up at 1/1/1970 and drops that date in as soon as it gains focus.  I need a way to validate whether or not someone has selected a date, but am stuck and can't find any real help online.  I am not looking to set the customformat = "", so please do not respond with that solution.  I need the actual value to be blank or something I can run validation against to know that the user has in fact selected a date.

Comment: Is there a specific value that they should be selecting?  If you are using a datepicker, you should be able to set the MinDate/Max Date.

Comment: There are a gazillion nullable DTPs at codeproject.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `ShowCheckBox` property to true. That will make the control look like this...

[image: DateTimePicker]

When the user selects a date, it will check the checkbox. Then when you need the value...

```
If datePicker.Checked Then
    'user has selected a value
Else
    'user has NOT selected a value
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the [ValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.valuechanged.aspx) event to set a flag to tell you they've clicked on a date?

### UPDATE

You could also use the [OnClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onclick.aspx) method to set a flag to verify the user actually clicked on the DateTimePicker.

Comment: I agree, using the ValueChanged event would be best.  Then if he needs the dates in a specific range, use the MinDate/maxDate funcationality.

Comment: I've tried value changed.  Problem is if the user is actually selecting the same date as what I set to be the value that the event doesn't trigger.  For example, if the value of the datepicker is today and the user is actually trying to assign today's date to the transaction, then the value changed event doesn't fire.

Comment: If you need the date, what are you doing with it?  What is supposed to happen after the date is selected?

Comment: The date is just the date that the user is assigning to indicate when the transaction took place.  It might be today it might be a month ago.  When the date is selected from the datepicker, the value needs to change to whatever was selected.

Comment: @jmease I think we need a little more info on what you are trying to achieve. Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: I am simply trying to achieve the equivalent of a required field validator on a datepicker. I need a way to tell that the date field was acknowledged so I can prevent them from submitting without having selected a date. There is no code.  There is a datepicker control and what I need is the code to make the value of it null.